# NodeJS timer for function that calls itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I've got a Discord Bot and I want to check the database I'm using every a certain time looking for something.
So, I added this on my app.js:

```
setTimeout(functions.verifyEmptyTeams, 864000)
```

The thing is that after that time (the time in miliseconds is just for testing) it runs the fuction once and it loops. I added that same line at the end of the function so it does the same on loop.
The function is:

```
    verifyEmptyTeams: function verifyEmptyTeams(){
        console.log('Verifying Empty Teams');
        let getTeams = 'SELECT * FROM teams';
        let i = 0;
        con.query(getTeams, function(err, teamResults){
          if(err) return handleDisconnect();
          for (rowDataPacket in teamResults){
            let teamOwner = teamResults[i].teamOwner;
            let tournamentID = teamResults[i].tournamentID;
            let getPlayers = 'SELECT * FROM players WHERE teamOwner = ? and tournamentID = ?';
            let data = [teamOwner, tournamentID];
            con.query(getPlayers, data, function(err, resultPlayers){
                if(err) console.log(err);
                if(resultPlayers.length == 0){
                    let deleteTeam = 'DELETE FROM teams WHERE teamOwner = ? and tournamentID = ?'
                    con.query(deleteTeam, data, function(err){
                        if(err) console.log(err);
                    })
                }
            })
          }
        })
        setTimeout(verifyEmptyTeams(), 864000)
    }
```

Edit: Just to be more clear. It loops inmediatly instead of waiting the 15 minutes again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive call's syntax is incorrect:

```
setTimeout(verifyEmptyTeams(), 864000)
```

What this does is it invokes `verifyEmptyTeams` *immediately*, then passes its return value to `setTimeout`. You need to pass *just the function* to `setTimeout` instead, so that `setTimeout` can call it:

```
setTimeout(verifyEmptyTeams, 864000)
```

But for longer timeouts like these, it might be more appropriate to use something like [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) instead.

```
cron.schedule('*/864 * * * * *', verifyEmptyTeams);
```

Comment: Thank you man! That was really helpfull. It works now but I will investigate about cron.
Thank you!
(Can't mark your answer as correct, I have to wait 7 minutes)